# Database Questions (How to add pre implemented select statements)

Tags: java, database

Would like some pointers on the code below
trying to create a program that pulls from the created City database table that was created.
Wondering how to put pre-populated select statements into the query text area that I can select and submit instead of having to write it out and in the results area, I would like to separate the name and population

EDIT - Added the SQL searches and checked them
EDIT - ADDED a combo box (need to get the SQL statement in the comboboxes)
EDIT - Added labels
EDIT --->
Have been Editing this post, figuring out a lot of new things
added statements to a drop-down that go into the text box, but would like to figure out how to get them to read one way but when clicked on implement the SQL statement instead then I can submit  ---- > also trying to still figure out how to separate the bottom section into City name / Population and then set the population to be a double instead of the current numbers that spew out (example: 12354E7)

```
package population;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import java.sql.*;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
// What to Create
// 2 lanes seperating city / pop
// Already implanted quries to click and submit

// Sort cities by pop / ascending
//SELECT cityname FROM City ORDER BY population ASC

// Sort cities by pop / descending
//SELECT cityname FROM City ORDER BY population DESC

// Sort cities by name
// SELECT cityname FROM City ORDER BY cityname ASC

// get total pop of all cities
// SELECT SUM(population) FROM city

// get avg pop of all cities
// SELECT AVG(population) FROM city

// get the highest pop
// SQL statement below semi correct
// SELECT population FROM city WHERE population = (select max(population) from city)


// get the lowest pop
// SQL statement below semi correct
// SELECT population FROM city WHERE population = (select min(population) from city)

public class Population extends Application
{
   // Database URL.
   final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby:CityDB";

   // Controls for input and output
   TextArea queryTextArea;
   TextArea resultsTextArea;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // Launch the application
      launch(args);
   }

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage)
   {
      final int COL_SIZE = 50;
      final int ROW_SIZE = 10;
      final double SPACING = 10.0;

      // Build the query entry area.
      Label queryin = new Label("Type Custom Query Here");
      queryTextArea = new TextArea();
      queryTextArea.setPrefColumnCount(COL_SIZE);
      queryTextArea.setPrefRowCount(ROW_SIZE);

      // Build the query results area.
      Label queryout = new Label("Query Output");
      resultsTextArea = new TextArea();
      resultsTextArea.setPrefColumnCount(COL_SIZE);
      resultsTextArea.setPrefRowCount(ROW_SIZE);

      // Create the Submit button.
      Button submitButton = new Button("Submit");
      submitButton.setOnAction(new SubmitButtonHandler());

      // Combobox test????????????????
      Label querydroplabel = new Label("Select from drop down");
      ComboBox<String> querydrop = new ComboBox<>();
      querydrop.getItems().addAll(
              "Sort cities by population / acending",
              "Sort cities by population / descending",
              "Sort cities by name",
              "Get total population",
              "Get AVG population",
              "Get Highest population",
              "Get Lowest population");
      querydrop.setOnAction(event ->
      {
          queryTextArea.setText(querydrop.getValue());
      });


      // Put the controls in a VBox.
      VBox vbox = new VBox(SPACING,
              querydroplabel,
              querydrop,
              queryin, 
              queryTextArea,
              submitButton, 
              queryout, 
              resultsTextArea);
      vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
      vbox.setPadding(new Insets(SPACING));

      // Set the title.
      primaryStage.setTitle("Enter a SELECT Query");

      // Create a scene and set it to the stage.
      Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);

      // Show the stage.
      primaryStage.show();
   }

   /**
    * Event handler class for submitButton
    */

   class SubmitButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
   {
      @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent event)
      {
         try
         {
            // Clear the previous results.
            resultsTextArea.setText("");

            // Create a connection to the database.
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);

            // Create a Statement object.
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            // Execute the query.
            ResultSet resultSet = 
                    stmt.executeQuery(queryTextArea.getText());

            // Get the result set meta data.
            ResultSetMetaData meta = resultSet.getMetaData();

            // Create a string to hold the results
            String output = "";

            // Get the results.
            while (resultSet.next())
            {               
               // Get a row.
               for (int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); i++)
               {
                  output += resultSet.getString(i);
                  output += '\t';
               }
               output += '\n';
            }

            // Display the results.
            resultsTextArea.setText(output);

            // Close the statement and the connection.
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();

         }
         catch (SQLException e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: looks like you should  use a `JComboBox` - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

Comment: Edited and added a combobox now need to get this box to have custom statements attached to it